# How to install(update) apk without the user prompt or user intervention in android

Tags: android

I want to update the apk without user intervention, or install new apk without user prompt.

Once download of new apk is done install the apk silently.

I tried with command line to install but still gives below error:

> java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working Directory: null Environment: null

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    if(isRooted()){
        Log.d("FTP_DOWNLOAD", "Device is ROOTED");
        Process process = null;
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "SmartPOS.apk";
        // call to superuser command, pipe install updated APK without writing over files/DB
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream outs = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            String cmd = "pm install -r " + path;
            outs.writeBytes(cmd + "\\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("FTP_DOWNLOAD", "ERROR Exception in onPostExecute():" + e.toString());
        }
    }else {
        Log.d("FTP_DOWNLOAD", "Device not ROOTED");
    }
    mProgress.dismiss(); //Dismiss the above Dialogue
}
```

Comment: Note that this might not be possible as this is very dangerous. May I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Its not a public app , its a Enterprise in house application (mobile point of sale) only 10 users ,so I need to update the app when new update is done in my code without user intervention